What does `**\/[^_]*.md^` in Astro glob() Match?
In The docs for the new Astro 5.0.0 release, the new syntax for content collections is introduced docs are here
In there, I see a glob pattern **\/[^_]*.md but not how this should differ from **\*.md. Can anyone help out here? Globs are not regexes so I don't think these are filenames that start with a _or ^ or do not start with an underscore. Does this indicate it looks for references to similar files?

as a guess, that would match any file ending in .md without an underscore anywhere in the filename

Well, after some further reading, turns out it behaves like grep or other regexes after all. It excludes files starting with _ from being globbed.
Astro does not build directories or files starting with an underscore.

Edited. Yep, good Idea.

cheers, made a minor edit because your answer is going to be around for decades, whereas comments asking for edits typically get deleted once edits are made =)
